# With Postgresql v10 and WAL2JSON... Is it possible to include the database name / datname in the json?

Tags: postgresql, multi-tenant, plugins

We have a set of databases that were not set up in a multi-tenant fashion. Looking to build a hub that will hold the data in a multi-tenant fashion using wal2json to pipe data from source to the hub. With each JSON object, I need to know which database it's coming from. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible because AFAIK database name or related oid is not stored in JSON columns. But it is always possible to retrieve current database name in a SQL session with:

```
select current_database();
```

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for a cluster-wide way of getting all activity from one cluster that is not multi-tenant to another one that is going to be a multi-tenant warehouse of that data. I'm grateful for any advice anyone might have.